# How to give STDIN in php without taking STDOUT from a file

Tags: php, json

How can I give STDIN to a php file from commandline directly ?

Currently I am doing like this : 
cat test.txt | php myfile.php

and test.txt contains a json object lie this:

> {"Name":"XYZ","Age":"25"}

I want to give {"Name":"XYZ","Age":"25"} directly as STDIN with out involving a file, just copy pasting the contests to commandline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '{"Name":"XYZ","Age":"25"}' |  php myfile.php
```

Comment: Any other way without using pipe operator ?

Comment: How  about fscanf?

Comment: Doing '{"Name":"XYZ","Age":"25"}' , am I not converting my JSON to a string ?

Comment: yes you are, that should not make a difference because in case **cat** also you are converting JSON to string.